# ExpressJS Cookie works on 'localhost' but not on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, express, nginx

I'm trying to set cookies for a logged-in user from my Node/Express server. My cookies are working just fine when my browser address is `http://localhost:4000/whatever`, however I have a certain oAuth integration that *can't* be returned to `localhost` and must got to the ip `127.0.0.1` (thanks Mailchimp).

None of my cookies are available on this address.

In my Express route I set a cookie like this:

```
 res.cookie('org_id', String(newOrgDoc._id), {expires:new Date(new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10))});
```

This used to make a persistent cookie, that I could access using Angular's `$cookies.get('org_id')`.

Is this some sort of cross-domain issue? How can I set a cookie that will work on both addresses?

Presumably this will be an issue in production, as I run an `nginx` server which maps a hostname to a localhost port (so I have my Express app running on `localhost:4000`, while the user is browsing via `http://whatever.com`. In this case, will the cookies set at localhost work in the user's browser?

Comment: Cookies are bound to hostname. Cookies cannot (or at least must not) be bound to IP address. So you do something wrong.

Comment: In case of nginx, cookies will be set to `whatever.com`